# Reference for Inception-v2

Tags: machine-learning, references, tensorflow

Cross-posted from [Data Science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53779/reference-for-inception-v2).

The "[Rethinking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf)" paper doesn't describe the [actual implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py) of the Inception-v3 model in Tensorflow: an accurate description is written in model.txt in the source files of the paper in the arXiv. Also the [Inception-v2 implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v2.py) differs from the paper: referring to the figures in the paper, the implemented v2 is 2xfigure5 + 1xfigure10 + 4xfigure5 + figure10 + 2xfigure5. Does anybody know why it was implemented this way and not in a more faithful way?